# prove the following $(A^t)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^t$

Tags: linear-algebra

$(A^t)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^t$

Proof:

$(A^{-1})^{t}*A^T=(A*A^{-1})^t=I$

How to continue from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conclude:

"From the above, we conclude $(A^T)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T$".

The justification for this step is as follows: for any matrix $A$, if $B$ is a matrix such that $BA = I$, then it follows that $B = A^{-1}$.

Or, equivalently: 
$$
(A^{-1})^{T}A^T=I \implies\\
(A^{-1})^{T}A^T (A^T)^{-1}=I (A^T)^{-1} \implies\\
(A^{-1})^{T} = (A^T)^{-1}
$$

Comment: Hmm, is it really true that $BA=I\implies B=A^{-1}$? Couldn't $A$ fail to have a 2-sided inverse, but still have a left inverse? Of course, in this question, it seems that $A$ is implicitly invertible as $A^{-1}$ is used in the statement of the question.

Comment: @MPW If $A$ is square then $BA = I \implies BAB = B \implies AB = I$.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: The first implication is clear. The second is not. It amounts to saying "if $B(AB)=B(I)$, then $AB=I$ by cancellation". That's simply not true, on the face of it, because there are zero divisors in the world of matrices. In other words, if $XY=XZ$, which is equivalent to $X(Y-Z)=0$, then it is *definitely not* necessary that either $X=0$ or $Y-Z=0$. Can you furnish a proof, or a link to one?

Comment: @MPW Yeah that was sloppy of me.  How about $BA = I \implies \det(BA) = 1 \implies \det(B)\det(A) = 1 \implies \det(A) \ne 0$?

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Ah, yes indeed. Now I see, you've hit it now. That means $A$ is invertible, so you can immediately say "$BA =I$ implies $BAA^{-1}=IA^{-1}$, that is, $B=A^{-1}$". Quite nice, thanks for the observation that makes it clear. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

$(A^{t})^{-1}=(A^{-1})^{t} \iff I=A^{t}(A^{-1})^{t}=(A^{-1}A)^{t}=I^{t}=I$

Note: $A$ is invertible because $A^{t}$ is invertible ($det(A)=det(A^{t})$) and $(AB)^{t}=B^{t}A^{t}$